# Should 'make install' depend on compilation?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have always written build (compilation) and install as completely different (to make(1), even unrelated) stages.  I could even write them in two separate Makefiles since they are completely isolated.

But a year ago or so, I wrote a Makefile where I specified the dependencies between install and compilation, and noticed some good things.

See the following minimal example:

```
.PHONY: all
all: build

.PHONY: build
build: foo

.PHONY: install
install: /usr/local/bin/foo

foo: foo.c
    cc -o $@ $<

/usr/local/bin/foo: foo
    install -m 755 -T $< $@
```

Should `/usr/local/bin/foo` depend on `foo` or not?

Reasons to state the dependency:

- Only install if necessary (if `foo` was recompiled).
  Of course, that saves considerable install time.
- The Makefile can compile something if we forgot to compile it (but see below).

Reasons to *not* state the dependency:

- Make sure that you never compile accidentally as root.
- Make sure you install the correct files,
  even if they were edited more recently than the compiled files.
  This would be similar to the concept of a reinstall.
  But for that rare scenario, one could run 'make uninstall && make install'.

Comment: Hi, opinion based questions do not belong on SO.

Comment: @blami I know it's a bit opinion based (I had doubts before asking it); but at the same time, it's a convention, and I'd like to know what users can expect from a Makefile, so that I don't break their expectations for no good reason.  But if there's consensus that there's no possible objective answer to this question, I'll understand it.

Comment: By convention yes, `make install` will build _and_ install the software.  It's not required to run `make all && make install`, typically.

Answer (score 0):

The [GNU Make Manual, section Standard Targets](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/html_node/Standard-Targets.html), lists several standard targets and what make users should expect from them. About the `install` target:

> Compile the program and copy the executables, libraries, and so on to the file names where they should reside for actual use. If there is a simple test to verify that a program is properly installed, this target should run that test.

As for running make as root, I think most do `sudo make install` without second thoughts. If you're not sure what the makefile will do you can review the output of `make -n install` for any shenanigans (after running `make all` to review just the install part).

Comment: Although there's a small security problem running the compiler as root, the main concern is having to `sudo make clean` afterwards, so that plain `make` will work, since root owns the modified files.  But yes, not much of a problem, and the benefit is considerable in some big projects.